# Unable to start AWS instance after stopping and starting due to retired AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have received a notification from AWS stating one of my instances is going to retire. My instance is backed by EBS and it has an Elastic IP.

I have proceeded with the simple process of stopping the instance and starting it again. The stop action processed correctly, but when I try to start it again it says:

> **Error starting instances**
>
> The requested configuration is currently not supported. Please check
>   the documentation for supported configurations.

Can someone explain what the problem is?

Note: To be on the safe side before stopping the instance I created an AMI of that instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AWS documentation indicates this error is due to your launch configuration:

> Cause: Some options in your launch configuration might not be
>   currently supported. Solution: Create a new launch configuration.
>   Update your Auto Scaling group with the new launch configuration using
>   the [update-auto-scaling-group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/update-auto-scaling-group.html) command.

- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/ts-as-instancelaunchfailure.html#ts-as-instancelaunchfailure-3

My guess would be that your launch configuration references the retired AMI. As such you'd need to create a new launch configuration and change your Auto Scaling Group to use that new configuration instead.

Comment: Mark,Thanks for your immediate response .Strangely I even though error came .New instance got launched and existing instance is terminated automatically .I have reattached the elastic IP, Is there something to worry and do some actions or everything is fine?

Comment: If you are using an Auto Scaling Group then I think you will need to take the action I described to ensure that Auto Scaling is able to work correctly.